# Dynamic OLS: serial correlation in the residuals

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, cointegration

I want to estimate cointegrating vectors between different I(1) time series. I used the R package CointReg to run D-OLS regressions (function CointRegD).

The number of lags and leads was selected by AIC.

I then used the Jarque-Bera and Ljung-Box tests to test for, respectively, normality and serial correlation in the residuals. Normality looks good but the residuals are serially correlated in all my specifications. If I was using VAR I would address this by removing the outliers, but I am not sure what to do in this case or if serial correlation is even an issue when using D-OLS.

Hence, my question is: how do I deal with serially correlated residuals in DOLS?

Many thanks in advance.